# What are the necessary conditions to use a custom AngularJS directive ?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

What are the necessary conditions to use a  custom  Angular directive ? 
i mean why we have to use custom directive instead of normal HTML tag !!

Comment: You don't *have* to. But I prefer using a simple custom tag with its encapsulated behavior in 2 (or more) pages rather than duplicating 20 lines of HTML and the same amount of JS code every time I want the same widget on two pages.

Comment: 1)you can perform complex  DOM manipulations inside directive.  2)re-usability.  3)more readable HTML code.

Comment: Thanks #JBNizet and Divya !!! 
Now i understand why use a custom directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom directives are really useful in many ways. One of them which will answer your question is following. If you have multiple div tags in your html, and you want the directive to be called only for a particular div only. In that case its better to use custom directive. If you do not use a custom one here, then you will need to check the id of the element or do something else which will help you determine if its your wanted element or not. This will add extra processing and also futher extra processing will be added by directive call for every unwanted div tag in that html